# bash compare two columns with exact match

Tags: awk

I am comparing columns between two files for exact match but I am ending up with inaccurate result. Example as follows.

```
File1   File2
adam    sunny
jhon    adam
kelly   adam
matt    kevin
stuart  adam
Gary    Gary
```

When we look at the files there is only match i.e. Garry. My output should be following.

```
Emptyline
Emptyline
Emptyline
Emptyline
Emptyline
Gary
```

In order to achieve requirement. I am running the following command

```
awk 'NR==FNR { n[$1]=$0;next } ($1 in n) { print n[$1],$2 }' file1 file2
```

and I am getting output as follows

```
adam
adam
adam
Garry
```

Comment: check `man comm`, may be it is one you need. Your current approach is not correct

Comment: `comm` does require sorted files. If order needs to be preserved it won't work.

Comment: Kindly do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS correctly as they are still not looking good(after my editing too).

Comment: @Shawn correct, yet who knows what inquirer actually needs

Answer (score 2):

You should be tracking line numbers, not just line contents:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { lines[NR]=$0; next }
       { if ($0 == lines[FNR]) print; else print "" }' file1.txt file2.txt





Gary
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With simple `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} a[FNR]==$0{print;next} {print ""}'  file1  file2
```

OR as per anubhava sir's comment:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} a[FNR]!=$0{$0=""} 1' file1  file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first file Input_file1 is being read.
  a[FNR]=$0        ##Creating an array a with index FNR and value of current line here.
  next             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
a[FNR]==$0{        ##Checking condition if value of array a with FNR index and current line is equal then do following.
  print $0,a[FNR]  ##Printing current line and value array a with index FNR here.
}
'  file1  file2    ##Mentioning Input_file names here
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Considering that your actual Input_file(s) have only 2 columns as per shown samples, could you please try following then.

```
paste Input_file1  Input_file2 | awk '$1==$2{print $1};$1!=$2{print ""}'
```

This code will only print lines whose values are equal in Input_file1 and Input_file2.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} a[FNR]!=$0{$0=""} 1` might be shorter.

Comment: Thanks a ton RavinderSingh13, it worked for me. I spent some good time to come to this solution but there was no luck, thanks again.